# Split String into array and insert it into datagridview

Tags: arrays, string, vb.net, datagridview, split

I have a string of the form "1|2,3|4,56|7|8|9,10|93". This strin shall be split into an array at the "|". This array is then inserted into a 1-column datagridview.

I wrote this:

```
Private Function foo(input As String)

        If input <> "" Then
            Dim StringTable() As String = Split(input, "|")
            Dim length As Integer = StringTable.Length
            Debug.Print("length " & length)

            For i = 0 To length - 1
                Debug.Print(StringTable(i))
                dg_ctdi.Rows.Add()
                dg_ctdi.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value = StringTable(i)
            Next
        End If

    End Function
```

Problem is, that "length" is now always 1, no matter how many elemenets the string has. Thus my datagridview has only one row. What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Your posted code inserted 7 rows into my grid.  Problem is something else.  Use the debugger to inspect the values as you step from line to line.

Comment: Maybe the character forming the divider in the input string is not actually the same as the one in the call to Split.

Comment: **[Using the Step Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx)**.  You should also set `Option Strict On`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the piece of code did the job correctly. Unfortunately I had some issues with the database-fild, where the input was previously stored. So feel free to use this code and have a look at the comments above. Thanks!